# Rendering a selected part of the terrain with different shading

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to understand how to modify the shading of the section of the terrain based on some user selection. In a game like Civ5, when a user selects a city or unit, that area is lit up more than the other parts of the terrain. I'm trying to implement this effect.

In the civ 5 example the selected tile is has a circle outline and the selected city has a transparent overlay that follows the height of the terrain nicely.

My current pipeline so far is at a primitive state. I render a quad and texture it with a grass texture. Then I draw a rectangular grid on top of this (a set of lines, with a slightly higher height value than the background grid). Upon selection (ie a mouse click inside the grid area), I calculate the approriate grid index by converting mouse to world coordinates and then to grid coordinates, and highlight the appropriate grid rectangle by changing the color of that particular rectangle. But, my approach gets outdated the moment I get a height map (as it assumes constant height), and looks pretty bad, hence this question.

[image: Civ5 screenshot]

EDIT : Added my pipeline description

Comment: There are plenty of ways to achieve that. Perhaps you could describe your existing pipeline?

Comment: Usually this isn't done by modifying the terrain's rendering, but by layering additional rendering on top — like an additively blended sprite or decal, or additional lights. To walk you through how to add such effects, it would be useful to see what we're building upon. Can you show how you're handling your map rendering so far?

Comment: I described my pipeline. It is still at a primitive state and looks bad.

Comment: To handle varying height within a tile, you may want to look into the keywords "decal" (particularly deferred decals or screen space decals) - a set of techniques for placing a local accent texture/effect onto other geometry - or "projector" - a similar effect achieved by "shining" the new texture onto the geometry, though it tends to cause more overdraw than decals.

Comment: Thanks. I know about projective texture mapping, but wasn't sure how to use that exactly. The reading on decals seem to be what I've been missing. Thanks!